# Toggle opacity of control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have button, which should toggle `Opacity` of element. Currently it works only at half - on click make control visible( set opacity to 1). I've tried use `ToogleButton` instead of simple `Button` to use properties `IsChechecked` (I think it is the same as `IsClicked`) but what I found wasn't good for me, cause for this properties I can't set `TargetName` for animation.

```
<ToggleButton BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Grid.Column="0" Padding="0" Grid.Row="0" Focusable="False" Width="Auto" PreviewMouseUp="Share_Click">
                        <ToggleButton.Content>
                            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Margin="0,0,6,0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Filter" Foreground="#FFC0B6D1" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="14" />
                                <Image Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,4,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="6" Width="12" Name="FiltersToggleArrow" Style="{StaticResource ToogleFilters}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ToggleButton.Content>
                        <ToggleButton.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.PreviewMouseDown">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="0:0:0.00" Storyboard.TargetName="FiltersPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:00.2" AutoReverse="False"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ToggleButton.Triggers>
                    </ToggleButton>
```

Comment: @StepUp, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MSDN documentation says:

> You can set this property to the name of any element within the scope of where the setter collection (the collection that this setter is part of) is applied. This is typically a named element that is within the template that contains this setter.

To get around this, you can instead apply your `Storyboard` inside the `Style` of your `Panel`, not the `ToggleButton`. In this case, you can use a `DataTrigger` to **bind** to the `IsChecked` property and act accordingly.

Here's an example I did with a `ToggleButton` and a `Rectangle`.

```
<ToggleButton Content="Switch" Name="chk"/>

<Rectangle Fill="Red" Name="rect"
            Width="50" Height="50">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chk}" Value="False">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="1"
                                                    To="0"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <DoubleAnimation From="0"
                                                    To="1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

From my experience with triggers, they can be a royal pain in the backside and are tricky to get right. That being said, this example should be enough to fit your requirements.